# Real fft error - ffmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, fft

I am trying to use ffmpegs fft utility for audio samples called real fft(rdft).

But I have SIGSEGV error. Code is very simple.

```
 static void fft(float* data){
    RDFTContext * ctx = av_rdft_init(Globals::WindowSizePower, DFT_R2C)
    av_rdft_calc(ctx, data);
    av_rdft_end(ctx);
    av_free(ctx);
  }
```

Defined constants are

```
static const int WindowSize = 1024;
static const int WindowSizePower = 10;
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I tried to find example on internet where this ffmpeg utility is used but I didnt find any.

EDIT:

This is function which call this function

```
void fftInit(float* correction){
        m_fft_data = new float[Globals::WindowSize]();
        memcpy(m_fft_data, correction, sizeof(float)*Globals::WindowSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < Globals::WindowSize; ++i){
            m_fft_data[i] *= m_data[i];
        }

        FFMPEGFFT::fft(m_fft_data);
    }
```

Input data is properly allocated. I tested extracted data before coming to this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `av_free` after `av_rdft_end` is **incorrect**. `av_rdft_end` already frees the memory space pointed to by `ctx`.

(Moreover, a semicolon is missing after `av_rdft_init`.)

Edit:

The second problem is that the operator `new[]` returns improperly aligned pointer. Use e.g. `av_malloc` instead. `av_malloc` allocates a block with alignment suitable for all memory accesses (including SSE instructions).

Comment: semicolon missing is copy error. But i get error on av_rdft_calc function not later...

Comment: @Steva: Is the `data` allocated properly? Can you show how the `fft` function is called?

Comment: Of course, I edited question. Data is allocated properly, I tested that first.

Comment: @Steva: The `fftInit` code seems to be OK. The problem must be somewhere else in your code. Have you checked the code using valgrind tool? Anyway, the `av_free` call is still incorrect.

Comment: I got sigsev on av_rdft_calc. I am using valgrind, whole other code is clean, without any error or memory leak. First time my app reach rdft_calc call it crashes. I am aware for av_free, I will remove it. But I didn't reach that problem, it is crashing before. Is problem if data has all 0s? Or something data related? Is enum I am using correct?

Comment: @Steva: 0s are not the problem. I came to the conclusion that your operator new[] returns improperly aligned pointer. Use e.g. `av_malloc` instead. `av_malloc` allocates a block with alignment suitable for all memory accesses (including SSE instructions).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :) Thank you :)